# To take the x axis value of the y axis maxima

Tags: python

When I run this code, I am getting an error of 'TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable'. I am a newbie. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
df_60Methanol = (pd.read_csv("40% Ethanol and 60% Methanol.csv", sep=';'))
Methanol1 = df_60Methanol.dropna()
plt.plot(Methanol1["Wavelength"], Methanol1["Intensity"])
a= Methanol1["Wavelength"]
b= Methanol1["Intensity"]
max1 = Methanol1["Intensity"].max()
xvalue= a[b.index(max1)]
print(xvalue)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`b.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) is a RangeIndex of the generated dataframe and has nothing to do with the [index method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index) of a list.

If you want to access the value of another column at a maximum, you can first [filter the dataframe](https://towardsdatascience.com/8-ways-to-filter-pandas-dataframes-d34ba585c1b8) and then access the other column.

So you can replace

```
max1 = Methanol1["Intensity"].max()
xvalue= a[b.index(max1)]
```

with

```
max_filter = Methanol1["Intensity"] == df["Intensity"].max()
filtered_df = Methanol1[max_filter]
xvalue = filtered_df["Wavelength"]
```